# how to give update app in flutter using in_app_update

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

```
           import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
          import 'package:gamershub/Screens/add_amount.dart';
  import 'package:gamershub/Screens/home_body.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
  import 'package:gamershub/Screens/splash_screen.dart';
  import 'package:gamershub/Screens/wallet.dart';
  import 'package:in_app_update/in_app_update.dart';
  import 'Screens/login.dart';
  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
AppUpdateInfo _updateInfo;
bool isLoading = false;
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

void _showError(dynamic exception) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
      content: Text(
        exception.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15,
          color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Quicksand", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
 }

   Future<void> checkForUpdate() async {
  setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
  });
  InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) {
  setState(() {
    _updateInfo = info;
  });
}).catchError((e) => _showError(e));

    setState(() {
  isLoading = false;
  });
}

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
// checkForUpdate();
   }

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   home: isLoading
      ? Center(
          child: SpinKitCircle(
            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
            size: 50.0,
          ),
        )
      : _updateInfo.updateAvailable == true ? Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg3.jpg"),fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ),
    child: AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
      title: Text("New Update Available! Please Update",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Quicksand", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
          ),),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(onPressed: _updateInfo?.updateAvailable == true
                ? () {
                    InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate().catchError((e) => _showError(e));
                  }
                : null,
                 child: Text("Update",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Quicksand", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
            ),))
          ],
    ),
  ) :OnboardingScreen(),
  routes: {
    '/login': (ctx) => LoginPage(),
    '/home': (ctx) => HomeBody(),
    '/addamount': (ctx) => AddAmountPage(),
    '/wallet': (ctx) => WalletPage(),
  },
 );
}
 }
```

I have created a project which is of version 1.0.0 and i have to upload it on playstore and i have used the plugin in_app_update to give the immediate update in the app when i make any changes to the apk and upload it on playstore but. I have wrap the home of the application to check first new version is there or not, but after hot reload i am getting an error  _updateInfo has getter length is null how to fix that??

```
       I/flutter (14077): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14077): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building 
    MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#0dab4):
I/flutter (14077): The getter 'updateAvailable' was called on null.
I/flutter (14077): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14077): Tried calling: updateAvailable
I/flutter (14077):
I/flutter (14077): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (14077):   MyApp 
 package:gamershub/main.dart:9
  I/flutter (14077):
I/flutter (14077): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

Comment: Maybe it's this line: `if (_updateInfo.updateAvailable... `? Should be : `_updateInfo?.updateAvailable != null &&`

Comment: Could you add full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: In the package https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update they have given a statement

Comment: Be aware that this plugin cannot be tested locally. It must be installed via Google Play to work. Please check the official documentation about In App Updates from Google.

Comment: May be for this i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from this:

```
: _updateInfo.updateAvailable == true ? Container(
```

Change it to:

```
:_updateInfo?.updateAvailable != null &&  _updateInfo.updateAvailable == true ? Container(
```

Comment: What about this statement    (Be aware that this plugin cannot be tested locally. It must be installed via Google Play to work. Please check the official documentation about In App Updates from Google.)

Comment: Your error comes from you own code, not the plugin; You simply can not retrieve _updateInfo, it's might be always null

Comment: @PrinceSingh That statement just means that the in-app updates api only works on apps installed from google play, you can't test it by locally installing the app from your code, you have to test it by publishing app on google play store and only then it can work, basically to test it you have to publish the app with this code added, then republish a newer update to see if you get prompted to update or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might be late but it will help others.

You have to follow below steps to test. Also please note you cannot test it on debug mode. You have to download the app from playstore and test it.

Follow this:

1. Make sure your test device has a version of your app installed that supports in-app updates and was installed using an internal app sharing URL.
2. Follow the Play Console instructions to share your app internally. Upload a version of your app that uses a version code that is higher than the one you already have installed on the test device.
3. On the test device, click the internal app sharing link for the updated version of your app but do not install the app from the Play Store page that appears after you click the link.
4. Open the app from the device's app drawer or home screen. The update should now be available to your app, and you can test your implementation of in-app updates.

For more information visit [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test):